# Is it always possible to find two elements $a,b\in G$ such that $\gcd(o(a),o(b))$ is composite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Suppose $G$ is an non-commutative group of order $n$.
>
> Is it always possible to find two elements $a,b\in G$ such that $\gcd(o(a),o(b))$ is composite?

**My try**:

I checked the groups $D_4,Q_8$.

I found that in $D_4$ we can find $r,r^2$ such that $o(r)=o(r^2)=4$.

Also the result holds in case of $Q_8$ as we can find the matrices

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i\\ i &0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i\\ i &0\end{bmatrix}$  which have orders $4$.

But I cant prove the result in general.

Is the result true or there are counter-examples to it?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Another question related to it is [Find all $n$ where it is always possible to find two elements $a,b\in G$ such that $\gcd(o(a),o(b))$ is composite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3330671/665065)

Comment: There are nonabelian groups in which every nontrivial element has prime order.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin; can you please construct such groups

Comment: Did you try the very smallest nonabelian group, Math_F?

Comment: @GerryMyerson; are you talking of $S_3$

Comment: Do you know a smaller nonabelian group, Math_F?

Comment: @GerryMyerson ,no

Comment: Then I guess that must be what I had in mind.

Comment: @GerryMyerson;i need to find all such non-abelian groups where this property holds

Comment: Then you should say so, and not in the comments, but in the title and body of the question. All they ask is whether it's always possible, etc., etc., and one counterexample is all it takes to show that it's *not* always possible, and that answers your question, the way you have asked it. If you now have a different question, then post the question that you now want to ask.

Comment: @GerryMyerson; should i delete this question

Comment: It's bad form to delete a question after someone has posted an answer.

Comment: @Math_Freak: Look up "nonabelian groups of order $p^3$". There is one of exponent $p$. Smallest one has 27 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no.

Pick any non-commutative group of order $pq$ where $p<q$ are distinct primes. Such a group exists when $q \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$. $S_3$ is the smallest example of such group.

Now, the claim trivially fails in that group (why?).

**P.S.** For $2$-groups the answer is yes, that's why it worked for your examples.

The easiest way to see this is the following: If $x^2 =e$ for all $x$ then $G$ is  Abelian. Thus, you can find an $x$ so that $x^2 \neq e$, and $a=x, b=x^{-1}$ is the example you are looking for.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97729/discussion-on-answer-by-n-s-is-it-always-possible-to-find-two-elements-a-b-in).