# Find all $n$ where it is always possible to find two elements $a,b\in G$ such that $\gcd(o(a),o(b))$ is composite?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

> Suppose $G$ is an non-commutative group of some finite order say $n$.
>
> Find all $n$ where $n$ is some possible order of a Non-Commutative Group $G$  where it is  always possible to find two elements $a,b\in G$ such that $\gcd(o(a),o(b))$ is composite?

**My try**:

I checked the groups $D_4,Q_8$.

I found that in $D_4$ we can find $r,r^2$ such that $o(r)=o(r^3)=4$.

Also the result holds in case of $Q_8$ as we can find the matrices

$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i\\ i &0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -i\\ i &0\end{bmatrix}$  which have orders $4$.

Also I found from previous question I posted here that the result fails for non-abelian groups of order $pq,2^n$ where $q\equiv 1 \mod p$

Related :[Is it always possible to find two elements $a,b\in G$ such that $\gcd(o(a),o(b))$ is composite?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3330624/665065)

How to find all such $n$ in general

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Edit your question so people can find your previous question on the topic. Then rewrite this question so it makes sense. It doesn't make sense to write, "I can't prove the result in general" when you haven't even stated a result.

Comment: @GerryMyerson; Edited ,please do have a look

Comment: As stated, this is possible in any group $G$ that has a single element $a$ whose order is composite. That's because there's no restriction that $b$ can't be $a^{-1}$ or some other power of $a$ with the same order as $a$ (including $b=a$ itself).

Comment: By the way, the example you claim to have found from $D_4$ is impossible: if $r$ is an element of order $4$ in some group, then $r^2$ definitely has order $2$.

Comment: @GregMartin; it will be $r^3$ sorry for that

Comment: Why downvotes? why is the question wrong

Comment: I can't make any sense of this question. You have fixed $G$ and $n$ in the first sentence, so it makes no sense to say "find all $n$". Do you mean find all $n$ such that there exists a group $G$ of order $n$ such that there exists elements $a,b$ such that ...?

Comment: @DerekHolt;yes you are right

Comment: @DerekHolt;does it make sense now,can you edit it accordingly?

Comment: Yes the question is better now, but note that you can always choose $b = a^{-1}$, so you are really just asking for the existence of an element $a$ of composite order in $G$.

Comment: @DerekHolt; yes thats true,is it possible to find all those groups which has one element of composite order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $G$ has no element of composite order, then there are clearly no such elements $a,b$.
If $G$ has an element $g$ of composite order, then $g^{-1}$ is a different element of the same composite order, so you can use $g$ and $g^{-1}$.
So the question is, for which values of $n$ does every nonabelian group of order $n$ have an element of composite order?
I don't know.
Certainly it's true for $n=2^m$, $m\ge3$. But I don't even know whether every nonabelian group of order $36$ has an element of composite order. (Although it shouldn't be too hard to look this up somewhere, as there are tables of small groups on the web.)

Comment: So is this problem not solvable for any $n\in \Bbb N$

Comment: For any individual value of $n$, it's a finite problem, so you can, in principal, solve it. Whether it is possible to solve it once and for all, for all $n$, I just don't know enough group theory to know whether that is possible.

Comment: So do you think its an open problem in group theory,do you know anyone who can answer this problem

Comment: How to solve it for some class of values like $p^n,pqr$ etc

Comment: So you think the question is asking whether the required property is true for all nonabelian groups of order $n$ rather than just for some nonabelian group of order $n$?

Comment: @DerekHolt; I dont get your point

Comment: @Math_Freak Consider $n=27$. Up to isomorphisms, there are two nonabelian groups of order $27$. In one of these, there exists $a,b$ of order $9$, so your property holds. But the other group has exponent $3$, so your property does not hold. I am unclear whether you would say that the property holds for $n=27$.

Comment: @DerekHolt;I want all non-isomorphic groups of given order to satisfy this

Comment: OK, so this is not true for any off prime power $n = p^k$ with $k \ge 3$, because there is a nonabelian group of exponent $p$. Among small $n$ it is true for $n=8,16,20,24,28,30,32,36,40$.